# Rspec : Declaring a variable that will be created into the method as record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sidekiq, rspec-mocks

I'm quite new to rails, but I seem to be facing an issue I cannot solve. I am trying to test a background job that will create a new record and use it later to instanciate a new service.

As I am testing a background job, it seems that I shoud be making a double of this service BEFORE the test, but one of the parameters is created whithin the job, using  another record that is created whithin the job as a reference. Hence, there will always be one difference in terms of ID everytime I try to run it.

Here is the sample code :

```
RSpec.describe UpdateVideoPerfDatasJob, :type => :job do
  it { expect(described_class).to be < ActiveJob::Base }
  context '#perform' do
    let (:split_test) { create(:split_test_for_result_slot) }
    let(:adwords_account) { split_test.adwords_account }
    let(:user) { split_test.adwords_account.user }
    let(:report_service) { instance_double('VideoPerformanceReportBis') }
    let(:api_service) { instance_double('GoogleAdsApiWrapper') }

    let(:campaigns_datas) { '#2 Api called...' }
    let(:segments_datas) { '#3 Api called...' }
    let(:data) { '#4 Global Array Created' }

    before do
      allow(VideoPerformanceReportBis).to receive(:new).with(split_test: split_test, adwords_account: adwords_account, user: user, result_slot: result_slot).and_return(report_service)
      allow(GoogleAdsApiWrapper).to receive(:new).with(adwords_account: adwords_account, user: user).and_return(api_service)
      allow(report_service).to receive(:refresh).with(no_args).and_return('#1 Refresh method')
      allow(report_service).to receive(:call_api_campaigns).with(no_args).and_return(campaigns_datas)
      allow(api_service).to receive(:get_campaigns).with(no_args).and_return('...and campaign gotten !')
      allow(report_service).to receive(:call_api_segments).with(no_args).and_return(segments_datas)
      allow(api_service).to receive(:get_campaigns_segments).with(no_args).and_return('... and segments gotten !')
      allow(report_service).to receive(:create_global_array).with(campaigns_datas, segments_datas).and_return(data)
      allow(report_service).to receive(:update).with(data).and_return('#5 update data')
```

```
class UpdateVideoPerfDatasJob < ApplicationJob
  def perform(split_test:, adwords_account:, user:)
    logger.warn 'Updating video performance data'

    history_log = HistoryLog.create(
      split_test: split_test,
      user: user,
      adwords_account: adwords_account,
      operation: 'Update vidéo performance data',
      messages: '',
      status: 'Initiated'
    )

    result_slot = ResultSlot.create(
      split_test: split_test,
      history_log: history_log,
    )

    result_slot.previous_result_slot_id = split_test.result_slot.id unless split_test.result_slot.nil?

    report_service = VideoPerformanceReportBis.new(
      split_test: split_test,
      adwords_account: adwords_account,
      user: user,
      result_slot: result_slot
    )

    response = report_service.refresh
    history_log.update!(
      messages: "Data updated on #{Date.today}",
      status: 'Video performance data updated'
    )
    NotificationsChannel.broadcast_to user, 'Finished Update Video Performance Data Worker'
  end
end
```

As you can see, the VideoPerformanceReportService is using a result_slot as parameter, that is created inside the job, using an history_log (also created inside the job) as a reference.

How can I test this ?

(Thank you in advance for everyone helping)

Comment: How can I test this? You can't. This method/object is doing way to much. That `before` block is totally bananas. Split this into a series of objects that each do a single job. A good litmus test is to see if you can write the class description without using the word "and".

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I decided to work on this during extra time so I do not have much back up from my leads (trying to show off as the intern :) ).

In a way to do it more efficiently, are you meaning that the background job should have more methods? One to create the history_log records, one to create the result_slot and then one to call the service, so everything is testable method after method using different "before"?

Comment: No I mean you should split this into separate jobs that each just do one thing.And then you create a job that ties it together. That way you test that just does what its supposed to and and you can just check that the job that ties it together calls the other jobs properly. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single-responsibility_principle

Comment: Allright, so here, we're basically creating a log that will be recording the operation. This should be in a different job, then the job that updates the db in another one, and then another job should be doing something like :
BigJob
Perform :
- CreateLogJob
- VideoPerfReportJob

Something like this?